# AWS athena query gzip format, missing column name in first row

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am generating a gz file that is csv by using below query

```
    CREATE TABLE newgziptable4
WITH (

            format = 'TEXTFILE',
            write_compression = 'GZIP',
            field_delimiter = ',',
            external_location = 's3://bucket1/reporting/gzipoutputs4'
        ) AS 

select name , birthdate from "myathena_table";
```

I am following this link [on aws website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html)

The issue is that if i just generate CSV, I see the column names as the first row in output csv. But when I use the above method, I do not see the column names `name` and `birthdate`. How can I ensure that I get those as well in the gz

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You would need to merge the output with a header file outside of Amazon Athena.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am in awe of your willingness to reply to my recent queries. When you say merge the output with a header file. So this is a gz file already written in S3 by athena. Do I have to now stream it and do whatever or you meant some other optimal way?

Comment: I have done similar with an extraction tool for SQL Server (`bcp`), where it exports without a header. After the export, I merge a 'header file' with the CSV 'data file'. It was a little easier than your situation because the files weren't compressed. So, you'd need a little script that can unzip, combine and re-zip.

Comment: I have seen some situations where people do `SELECT 'header1', 'header2', 'header3' UNION SELECT ...real query...`, but that can cause problems with fields that are not text/varchar. But, give it a try.

Comment: this is why i prefer gcp